# In Symfony2 - The route placeholder and the related controller argument have different type

Tags: symfony, controller, routes

I have a route as follows:

```
blog_post:
    path:  /{post_id}/{post_title}.{_format}
    defaults: { _controller: BlogBundle:Blog:post }
    requirements:
        post_id: \d+
        post_title: "[a-zA-Z0-9-]+"
        _format: 'html'
```

that is matched by the following URL:

```
www.website.com/32/my-best-story.html
```

I do not understand why the routing placeholder {post_id} (which is an integer as required in the route) and the related controller argument $post_id do not have the same type:

```
class BlogController extends Controller
{
    public function postAction(Request $request, $post_id, $post_title)
    {
        $type = gettype($post_id);
        var_dump($type);
        die();
    }
}
```

returns

```
string(6) "string"
```

I would expect it to return:

```
string(7) "integer"
```

Where am I wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not understand why the routing placeholder {post_id} (which is an integer as required in the route) and the related controller argument $post_id do not have the same type

Be careful, the requirement `\d+` means `digit` not `integer`

There is no concept of typing in routing placeholder.

Comment: ^^ Also, the routing component uses regular expressions to generate the variables that would be passed to your action, and those matches will always be returned as text (type `string`), even if you set the requirement to be all digits (`d\+` would match '0005' as different than '5', for example).

You could try using the [@ParamConverter]http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html to automatically convert to a Doctrine entity, or just typecast with `(int) $post_id`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers and explanations.  
@Jason actually I'm using (int) to typecast the controller argument at the moment (note: I do not use Doctrine). That's why I wondered about the typing in routing placeholder.  
"(...) those matches will always be returned as text" makes sense. Thanks.